# $\{K∈K(X):K⊆U\}$ for $U$ open in $X$ generates $\textbf{B}(K(X))$

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ be a Polish space.

The family of set

$(i)$ $\{K∈K(X):K⊆U\}$

$(ii)$ $\{K∈K(X):K∩U≠∅\}$

for $U$ open in $X$ generates $\textbf{B}(K(X))$ where $K(X)$ is the space of all compact  subsets of $X$.?

Any contribution'll be very grateful.

Comment: Actually, the sets in _(i)_ and _(ii)_ form a basis of the topology of $K(X)$; if $X $ is second countable, they must generate the Borel sets. Is the question in the title the relevant one? Please make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of the Vietoris topology the sets from (i) and (ii) form a subbase for the topology of the hyperspace $H(X)$ of $X$ (all non-empty closed subsets of $X$), and so also for its subspace $K(X)$. IIRC the Hausdorff metric $d_H$ on $K(X)$ (not generally defined on $H(X)$) generates this topology as well. I suppose you already know this; $(K(X), d_H)$ is a Polish space whenever $X$ is. E.g. the Kechris textbook covers this.

As $X$ is second countable (being Polish), the base from this subbase generates the topology as a $\sigma$-algebra as well, so this also holds for the subbase. 
So we know that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the subbase is indeed the same as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology, i.e. the Borel sets.