# Family of intersection compact with open set generates borel of compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ Polish space, and $K(X):\{K \subset X : K \text{ is compact}\}$

I need a hint how to prove the family of sets $\{K \in K(X): K \cap U \neq \emptyset\}$  and $\{K \in K(X): K \subset U\}$ generates $\mathbf{B}(K(X))$.

However, it's not a $\sigma$-algebra because the complement is not in the family. We know by this
[solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234751/k%E2%88%88kxk%E2%8A%86u-for-u-open-in-x-generates-textbfbkx) form a subbase of Vietoris topology, but the objective is to solve without knowing this fact.